# RubyMine Cannot switch SDK. RVM SDK '2.2.0@rails-devise' wasn't found

Tags: ruby, sdk, rubymine

I switch to new version of ruby  2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux], then RubyMine show me this blody message:

Cannot switch SDK. RVM SDK '2.2.0@rails-devise' wasn't found

When i go to RubyMine SDK Settings, i see, that evyrything is in place:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdIfr.png

Anyone can help me with that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug if your .ruby-version file contains only the version number. They're working on it here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-15058

Comment: I am using Rubymine 8.0.3, and the contents of .ruby-version are `ruby-2.2.0`. contents of .ruby-gemset are `rails420` but I still see the same error everytime - Cannot switch SDK. RVM SDK 'ruby-2.2.0@rails420' wasn't found

Answer (score 2):

RubyMine 6.3.3
I had the same problem.

Try to replace **.ruby-version** with **.ruby-gemset** and put inside

```
2.2.0@rails-devise
```

Comment: I am using Rubymine 8.0.3, and the contents of .ruby-version are `ruby-2.2.0`. contents of .ruby-gemset are `rails420` but I still see the same error everytime - Cannot switch SDK. RVM SDK 'ruby-2.2.0@rails420' wasn't found